# How to pass symbol & in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I have a `div class="hello&world"` for example.

How Can I use it on CSS file?

I tried that `.hello&world{display: none}` but I cant take & in that file.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: don't use & in css classes. it's not allowed

Comment: Bad naming convention... use something like hello_world or hello-world.

Comment: Ok cheers.. I am not gonna do that. How can I close this question?

Comment: Your question is similiar with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: You may check on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: No its not similar to that guys.. That is about valid characters. Mine is about how to pass that specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to escape the `&` with `\`

```css
.hello\&world {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello&world">test</div>
```